# Error al intentar arrancar squid desde aplicación web

Tags: php, symfony

Estoy confeccionando una interfaz web con PHP para administrar un servidor proxy Squid en Debian 11.

Las configuraciones las almaceno en una base de datos MySQL y otras en archivos dentro del directorio `/etc/squid/`. Ajustando los permisos de los archivos a modificar no tengo problemas para hacer las modificaciones desde la aplicación web.

Sin embargo mi problema está al intentar iniciar, detener, reiniciar o recargar el proceso de Squid.

Para esto, he creado un worker (mediante **Supervisor**) el cual se ejecuta de manera asíncrona y en el que empleo el componente Symfony Process para ejecutar el comando `systemctl start|stop|restart squid.service` pero no entiendo como otorgar permisos para que desde el cli se pueda ejecutar.

Este es el `worker` ejecutado desde ***Supervisor***:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Clase `SquidProxyOrdenMessageHandler`:**

```
final class SquidProxyOrdenMessageHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface {

    public function __invoke(SquidProxyOrdenMessage $message) {
        $orden = $message->getOrden();
        $params = $message->getParams();

        switch ($orden) {
            case "start":
                $resultado = SQUIDProcess::startSquidProxy();
                break;
            case "stop":
                $resultado = SQUIDProcess::stopSquidProxy();
                break;
            case "restart":
                $resultado = SQUIDProcess::restartSquidProxy();
                break;
            case "reload":
                $forceReload = false;
                if (is_bool($params)) {
                    $forceReload = true;
                }
                $resultado = SQUIDProcess::reloadSquid($forceReload);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Clase `SQUIDProcess`:**

```
class SQUIDProcess {

    public static function statusSquidProxy(): null|int {
        $executableFinder = new ExecutableFinder();
        $path = $executableFinder->find("systemctl");
        $process = new Process([$path, 'status', 'squid']);

        $process->run();
        return $process->getPid();
    }

    public static function startSquidProxy(): null|int {
        $executableFinder = new ExecutableFinder();
        $path = $executableFinder->find("systemctl");
        $process = new Process([$path, 'start', 'squid.service']);
//        $process = new Process(['/etc/init.d/', 'squid', 'start']);
        try {
            $process->mustRun();
            if ($process->isSuccessful()) {
                $pid = $process->getPid();
            }
        } catch (ProcessFailedException $exc) {
            throw new \Exception($exc->getMessage());
        }

        return $pid;
    }

    public static function stopSquidProxy(): null|int {
        $executableFinder = new ExecutableFinder();
        $path = $executableFinder->find("systemctl");
        $process = new Process([$path, 'stop', 'squid']);
        try {
            $process->mustRun();
            $pid = $process->getPid();
        } catch (ProcessFailedException $exc) {
            throw new \Exception($exc->getMessage());
        }

        return $pid;
    }

    public static function restartSquidProxy(): null|int {
        $executableFinder = new ExecutableFinder();
        $path = $executableFinder->find("systemctl");
        $process = new Process([$path, 'restart', 'squid.service']);
        try {
            $process->mustRun();
            $pid = $process->getPid();
        } catch (ProcessFailedException $exc) {
            throw new \Exception($exc->getMessage());
        }

        return $pid;
    }
}
```

Al ejecutar `startSquidProxy()` con `'systemctl start squid.service'` el error arrojado es el siguiente:

```
Handling "App\Message\SquidProxyOrdenMessage" failed: The command "'/bin/systemctl' 'start' 'squid.service'" failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: /var/www/html/squidmgr/public 
Output: 
================ 
Error Output: 
================ 
Failed to start squid.service: Interactive authentication required. See system logs and 'systemctl status squid.service' for details.
```

Si sustituyo `'systemctl start squid.service'` por `'/etc/init.d/squid start|stop|restart'` entonces el error es:

```
Handling "App\Message\SquidProxyOrdenMessage" failed: The command "'/etc/init.d/' 'squid' 'start'" failed. 
Exit Code: 126(Invoked command cannot execute) Working directory: /var/www/html/squidmgr/public 
Output: ================ 
Error Output: ================ 
sh: 1: exec: /etc/init.d/: Permission denied
```

Imagino la cuestión esté en que no se tiene acceso desde el proceso del cli de Apache a los script `systemctl` o `/etc/init.d/squid`.

¿Cómo se manejan estos casos? Inicialmente pensé que ejecutar el worker con el usuario `root` resolvía, pero evidentemente la seguridad en la ejecución de los procesos del apache y el squid no lo permiten.

Comment: Unas preguntas: ¿qué sistema operativo estás usando? ¿tienes `selinux` habilitado? ¿tienes alguna necesidad en especial de hacer uso de `supervisor` en vez de realizar la llamada directamente desde tu aplicación web? (imagino que esto último será para reducir la superficie de exposición, aunque una vez dentro del sistema el acceso a `supervisor` es el mismo que a `sudo`).

Comment: ¿Puedes comprobar que el proceso trabajador de `supervisor` esté ejecutándose realmente como `root`? Para ello usa, por ejemplo, `ps -ef | grep "messenger:consume"`.

Comment: Oscar relamente la idea era intentar ejecutar desde un worker con supervisor porque no sabia cómo resolver el tema de la seguridad entre los procesos. Con sudoers ya se resolvió y el código queda llamándose directamente desde la web. En un rato actualizo el resultado final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mensaje de error te está indicando que el sistema ha intentado solicitarte las credenciales para realizar la gestión del servicio pero que no ha sido posible crear una terminar interactiva para ello.

Para ejecutar tareas administrativas desde un usuario sin privilegios de manera controlada y sin que se solicite una contraseña es recomendable el uso de `sudo`.

Para ello deberás crear un archivo que se llame, por ejemplo, `/etc/sudoers.d/squid-apache` que contenga la siguiente línea:

```
www-data ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: \
    /etc/init.d/squid *, \
    /usr/bin/systemctl start squid.service, \
    /usr/bin/systemctl stop squid.service, \
    /usr/bin/systemctl restart squid.service
```

Deberás adaptar tu código para que en vez de llamar a:

```
/etc/init.d/squid start|stop|restart
/usr/bin/systemctl start|stop|restart squid.service
```

Hagas una llamada a:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/squid start|stop|restart
sudo /usr/bin/systemctl start|stop|restart squid.service
```

Además, la manera en la que has llamado a `/etc/init.d/squid start` parece no ser la correcta. Parece que ha tratado de ejecutar la ruta en la que se aloja el guión de arranque `squid`, `/etc/init.d/`, y no el guión de arranque.

PD: Si tienes un sistema operativo con `selinux` habilitado es probable que necesites habilitar algún parámetro adicional.

---

La explicación de la línea de configuración de `sudo` es la siguiente:

- Cuando el usuario `www-data`.
- Desde cualquier equipo (`ALL`).
- Solicite ejecutar algo como `root`.
- No pregunte la contraseña para hacerlo (`NOPASSWD:`).
- Solo se aplican estas reglas a la ejecución de las instrucciones enumeradas (`/etc/init.d/squid *`, etc).

Comment: Hola, agregado el usuario www-data a los sudoers y el worker de supervidor que se ejecute con el propio usuario www-data. Y funciona de maravillas!!!